# Slow 'ping' performance during name lookup phase

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

This morning I am encountering a strange network problem from my laptop. If I use `ping` from the command line (Xubuntu 19.04) then the name lookup phase is oddly slow, while the actual ICMP packets for ping work just fine.

```
$ ping cnn.com      # nothing happens for 5 seconds after hitting ENTER
PING cnn.com (151.101.193.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.193.67 (151.101.193.67): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=27.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.67 (151.101.193.67): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=40.1 ms
```

If I do the ping directly to the IP address then everything is fast and quick.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` has `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as the first entry.

If I do `dig @8.8.8.8 cnn.com` I get the answer back very quickly!

A puzzling observation if I look at `tcpdump` while I am attempting the `ping cnn.com`:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp1s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
08:04:54.005650 IP 192.168.43.147.54944 > 8.8.8.8.53: 9634+ A? cnn.com. (25)
08:04:54.005669 IP 192.168.43.147.54944 > 8.8.8.8.53: 9387+ AAAA? cnn.com. (25)
08:04:54.130322 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.43.147.54944: 9387 4/0/0 AAAA 2a04:4e42:200::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42:600::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42:400::323 (137)
08:04:59.010696 IP 192.168.43.147.54944 > 8.8.8.8.53: 9634+ A? cnn.com. (25)
08:04:59.197233 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.43.147.54944: 9634 4/0/0 A 151.101.193.67, A 151.101.65.67, A 151.101.129.67, A 151.101.1.67 (89)
08:04:59.197424 IP 192.168.43.147.54944 > 8.8.8.8.53: 9387+ AAAA? cnn.com. (25)
08:04:59.250245 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.43.147.54944: 9387 4/0/0 AAAA 2a04:4e42:600::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42:400::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42::323, AAAA 2a04:4e42:200::323 (137)
08:04:59.251266 IP 192.168.43.147 > 151.101.193.67: ICMP echo request, id 21287, seq 1, length 64
08:04:59.286265 IP 151.101.193.67 > 192.168.43.147: ICMP echo reply, id 21287, seq 1, length 64
```

So it seems that there are around 5 seconds worth of DNS queries, the first one returning IPv6, which apparently are just ignored, then another request, this time with IPv4 answers, another request, IPv6 again, and finally the ICMP packets for the actual ping.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Check if the same issue happens when you use 1.1.1.1 or a different DNS

Comment: Agree, try different DNS server and 2nd, try adding cnn.com to your /etc/hosts file and check timings.

Comment: Yes, it happens independently of the name server.